# How to 'and' data without ignoring digits?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a number, `18573628`, where each digit represents some kind of flag, and I want to check if the value of the fourth flag is set to `7` or not (which it is).

I do not want to use indexing. I want to in some way `and` with a flag mask, such as this:

`00070000`

I would normally use `np.logical_and()` or something like that, but that will consider *any* positive value to be `True`. How can I `and` while considering the value of a digit? For example, preforming the operation with

`flags = 18573628`

and

`mask = 00070000`

would yield `00010000`

though trying a different mask, such as

`mask = 00040000`

would yield `00000000`

Comment: you would usually use bits for masks, not decimal digits

Comment: @njzk2 of course, but in my context, each "bit" in `18573628` can be any number, not just on or off. Perhaps I would need some kind of 3-d bit mask

Comment: Do you need to be able to isolate multiple digits, or just a single one at a time?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "3d bit mask". The bitwise operations work because they're performed on _bits_. If you want to use decimal digits for "flags", which no one does, then you'll have to roll your own solution. You can't just invent your own system and expect existing tools to work the same way on it.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes, I toyed with that, but I don't understand its output for number with more than one digit: `123 & 103` gives `99`. I could turn the number `18573628` into a list, but I want to find another solution

Comment: @jphollowed 7 is 0b111, but 17 is 0b10001. The bits are completely unrelated. You can't use a bitmask for that.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Just so you're aware, I'm building this because I need to analyse flags given in Sloan Digital Sky Survey observational data, which are given exactly as I've described. For example, the `r-band` magnitude flags on a particular galaxy is `2252074960195600`. Each digit can have a different value, and they all mean different things. So I am not making up my own system, and obviously it is not true that "no one" uses decimal flags, as SDSS is a pretty large operation.

Comment: `I don't understand its output` it's a bitwise and. just convert to binary, make an and between the bits, and that's it.

Comment: If you want each decimal digit to be a flag, you may as well use a string `"18573628"` instead of an integer `18573628`.

Comment: FYI: http://www.sdss.org/dr12/tutorials/flags/ this is what we seem to be talking about, this as well: http://www.sdss.org/dr12/algorithms/photo_flags_recommend/. They are indeed binary values, and can be accessed / decoded in the usual way.

Comment: what you are looking at is not a number, it is a list of digits. use it as such.

Comment: Most useful: http://www.astro.princeton.edu/~rhl/flags.html. The flags can be "extracted" using the typical bit shift method.

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks for the links.  So the flags *are* standard bits in integers, and so standard bit operators can be used to access the flags.  I think the OP just needs some tips on what that means and how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is

```
if (x // 10**n % 10) == y:
    ...
```

to check if the `n`-th digit of `x` (counting from **right**) is equal to `y`

Comment: I'd upvote this, but don't want to ruin the juxtaposition of the values of your ID and rep.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use divide and modulo for a decimal mask:

```
flags = 18573628
mask = 10000

if (flags / mask) % 10 == 7:
    do_something
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the input number into an array of digit numbers and then simply indexing into that array with that specific index or indices would give us those digit(s). For doing that conversion, we can use `np.fromstring`, like so -

```
In [87]: nums = np.fromstring(str(18573628),dtype=np.uint8)-48

In [88]: nums
Out[88]: array([1, 8, 5, 7, 3, 6, 2, 8], dtype=uint8)

In [89]: nums[3] == 7
Out[89]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

> Say I have a number, `18573628`, where each digit represents some kind of flag, and I want to check if the value of the fourth flag is set to `7`

Firstly, bitwise operations like `&` are *bit*-wise, which is to say they operate on base-2 digits. They don't operate naturally on digits of any other base, although bases which are themselves powers of 2 work out ok.

### To stick with bit-wise operations

You need to know how many values each flag can take, to figure out how many bits each flag needs to encode.

If you want to allow each flag the values zero to nine, you need four bits. However, in this scheme, your number won't behave like a normal integer (storing a base-10 digit in each 4-bit group is called *Binary Coded Decimal*).

The reason it won't behave like a normal integer is that flag values `1,2,3` will be stored as `1 * 16**2 + 2*16 + 3` instead of the `1 * 10**2  + 2*10 + 3` you'd normally expect. So you'd need to write some code to support this use. However, extracting flag *n* (counting from zero at the right) just becomes

```
def bcdFlagValue(bcd, flagnum):
  if flagnum == 0:
    return bcd & 0x0F;
  return 0x0F & (bcd >> ((flagnum-1) * 4))
```

If you actually need a different range of values for each flag, you need to choose the correct number of bits, and adjust the shift and mask values appropriately.

In either case, you'll need a helper function if you want to print your flags as the base-10 number you showed.

---

### To use normal base 10 numbers

You need to use division and modulo (as 6502 showed), because base-10 numbers don't fit evenly into base-2 bits, so simple bit operations don't work

---

### Note

The BCD approach saves space at the cost of complexity, effort and some speed - from subsequent comments, it's probably simpler to just use the string of digit characters directly unless you really need to save 4 bits per digit.

Answer (score 0):

if `flags` and `mask` are hexadecimal values, you can do:

```
flags = int("18573628", 16)
mask = int("00070000", 16)
result = flags & mask

print(hex(result))
=> '0x70000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Without dealing with the particulars of your case (the SDSS data, which should be documented in the product specification), let's look at some options.

First, you need to to know if it is to be read in big-endian or little-endian order (is the first bit to the right or to the left). Then you need to know the size of each flag. For a series of yes-no parameters, it could simply be 1 bit (0 or 1). For up to four options, it could be two bits (00, 01, 10, 11), etc. It is also possible that some combinations are reserved for future expansion, don't currently have meaning, and should not be expected to occur in the data. I've also seen instances where the flag size varies, so first n bits mean refer to parameter x, next n bits refer to parameter y, etc.

There is a good explanation of the concept as part of Landsat-8 satellite imagery:
http://landsat.usgs.gov/qualityband.php

To read the values, you convert the base 10 integer to binary, and traverse it in the specified chunks, converting back to int to obtain the parameter values according to your product specification.